# Determining Austrian roads which are accessible for pedestrians from OpenStreetMap?

Tags: openstreetmap, austria

I've looked at the attributes/tags of the OSM highways but couldn't find any information about my issue.

Is there a way to receive the information which roads (of the OSM highway key) are accessible by pedestrians? I know there is the "pedestrian" value, but I would like to find out ALL roads where pedestrians are allowed to walk (they can not only walk on pedestrian roads, sometimes also on secondardy roads, etc, wich are accessible for cars and for pedestrians both).

Is it possible to get this information using OSM data? Or is there a good workaround?

My area of interest is the country of Austria. 
My target is to receive all roads where pedestrians can walk...so not only footways...they can also walk on roads which are usually for cars (and pedestrians). Excluded for example should be all motorways (and other roads).

Comment: Unfortunately the OSM tagging depends on the data available, and the traffic rules for all countries are not the same. Can you constrain the problem somewhat (e.g. a specific country or area)? Do you want footpaths, sidewalks, tracks in Africa, or is your need more specific?

Comment: thank you, I have edited and included my area of interest. My target is to receive all roads where pedestrians can walk...so not only footways...they can also walk on roads which are usually for cars (and pedestrians). Excluded for example should be all motorways (and other roads).

Comment: Can you just choose multiple `highway=` options, leaving out the ones you don't want?

Comment: yes, but I was hoping to find a way to avoid that...or at least to find an improved way to do that.

Answer (score 3):

You might have a look at the default access rules that are defined inside OpenStreetMap for each country:

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_tags_for_routing/Access-Restrictions#Austria

You see that all highways tagged as motorway, trunk, bridleway and cycleway are forbidden per se. You can add all highways that have `foot=yes`or `foot=designated` (overriding the default above), and remove all higways that have `foot=no`.

Comment: Also drop ways tagged with access=no *and not* foot=yes.

Depending on your use-case you might want to look for additional tags. For example if you want to search for ways that are safe to walk on then skip ways tagged with sidewalk=no or sidewalk=none (values no and none are synonymous) because these ways don't have a sidewalk and people have to walk on the road instead.

Comment: thank you for your help. So for accessing the roads for pedestrian-use I actually just need the "foot" tag? For downloading it then you would use an overpass turbo query where you would specify "foot=yes or "foot=designated"? Since I am new for accessing OSM data, how would you define such an overpass query, or would you access this data differently?

Comment: No, you need `highway`, `foot`, `access` and maybe `sidewalk`. Note that motorways usually don't have `foot=no`, and footways usually no `foot=yes` because it is implicated. Paths for bicylces and pedestrians along a highway can be tagged as `highway=cycleway` or `highway=footway`, allowing the other half with `foot=yes`or `bicycle=yes`.

Comment: thank you very much

Just for my understanding:

By default all roads except motorway/trunk, bridleway and cyeway should be available for pedestrians in Austria. So I could download the whole highway key (overpass turbo: highway = *) and then delete all motorways/trunks, bridleways and cycleways.

Then I have to delete the exceptions too, where access = "no", "private", "forestry", "customers", "agricultural", "destination?" and where foot="no", "private" and "official?". This should result in all highways available for pedestrians, correct?

Or would you download the data differently?

Comment: The download is ok, but before you delete bridleways and cycleways, make sure they have no `foot=yes` or `foot=designated`. This would override the default restriction. Furthermore: `foot=yes`would invert any `access=no`. I don't think that `access=agricultural` `forestry` or `destination` would imply any restriction for pedestrians. I suggest to visualize the highways on a OSM background with QGIS, and take a closer look on the tag combinations.

Answer (score 1):

GraphHopper has a grown (read: good ;)) mechanism to return all possible footpaths. So you could write a bit java code to export all geometries or whatever you need:

```
GraphHopper hopper = new GraphHopper().init(args);
hopper.importOrLoad();
Graph graph = hopper.getGraphHopperStorage();
FlagEncoder foot = hopper.getEncodingManager().getEncoder("foot");
EdgeExplorer ee = graph.createEdgeExplorer(new DefaultEdgeFilter(foot));
// start at the 'random' node 0 hopefully connected to the rest of the graph
new BreadthFirstSearch() {
     protected boolean checkAdjacent(EdgeIteratorState edge) {
          System.out.println(edge.getEdge() + " -> " + edge.fetchWayGeometry(2));
     }
}.start(ee, 0)
```

(note I'm the author)

Comment: Thank you for you input. Returning all geometries with a java code would be great, but since I am not familiar with java, it is not really possible for me. (Or is the given code actually all I need?!)

Comment: Yes, that is all you need (maybe some tweaks here and there as I did not test nor compile it). E.g. copy&paste into the Import file: https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/tools/src/main/java/com/graphhopper/tools/Import.java#L29 and run `./graphhopper.sh import your-osm.pbf`

Answer (score -1):

You can find that information mapped in `highway=footway` under `sidewalk=left;right;both`. See also the [Sidewalk description](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Sidewalks) in the OSM wiki.

Comment: thank you, but using the value "footway" does not lead to all roads which are accessible by pedestrians, it only leads to a part of it.

Comment: I see. In that case I can't help you, sorry.